# How to remove this part from URL using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have this URL:

```
http://www.register.abc.com/myapp/administrator/registration
```

Which is :

- http://www.register.abc.com is my domain
- myapp is my aplication folder in server
- administrator/registration is my controller and function

What I'd like to do is to remove this part `/myapp/administrator/registration` from my URL. In default, when user only enter the `http://www.register.abc.com/` it will be redirected to my home page. I'd like to set it so the user directly enter registration page not the home page. I have little to no knwledge about .htaccess. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Note: I am using wiredesignz codeigniter modular extensions hmvc

Edit:

my current .htaccess is like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /myapp
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please share your htaccess file in your question. Also could you please let us know which url you want to hit in browser and by which url you want to rewrite/redirect in backend? That will give us better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: I currently have no .htaccess file. I'd like user to enter `http://www.register.abc.com` and they go directly to my regist page, currently it's directed to home page

Comment: I'd like to rewrite `http://www.register.abc.com/myapp/administrator/registration` into `http://www.register.abc.com`

Comment: Sure, on SO its encouraged to put efforts in form of rules/codes in questioners questions(there is nothing wrong or right in efforts), so please do add it once, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your site root .htaccess (a level above `myapp/` you may try this .htaccess code:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ myapp/administrator/registration [L,R=302]
```

If you want an internal rewrite (without changing URL) then try:

```sh
RewriteRule ^$ myapp/administrator/registration [L]
```